# Way to set a data attribute or class on tag manager output?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have Google Analytics loaded through Google Tag Manager.

The output is as follows:

```
<script type="text/plain" async src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to set either a HTML data attribute or css class on this output somehow in Tag Manager? For example:

```
<script data-unblock class="unblock" type="text/plain" async src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

The context for this relates to automatic cookie blocking of scripts. My cookie solution allows to unblock scripts based on data attribute or css class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. You have the power to execute custom JS in GTM, hence find any tag and add any data-attribute to it.

You just need to execute a custom HTML tag on pageload, adding an inline script

Here, this code will add your data-unblock attribute:

```js
document.querySelector("script[src^='https://www.google-analytics.com']").setAttribute('data-unblock', "");
```

And this one will add the class if you like it more:

```js
document.querySelector("script[src^='https://www.google-analytics.com']").setAttribute('class', "unblock")
```

You can test both right here, on stackoverflow.